# Form Closing on X C#

Tags: c#, winforms

After an immense amount of reasearch I am still no closer to a solution.

I have a simple app, 2 forms .NETv3.5 C#.

The application loads the first form, i press 'X' on the windows bar.

The application hides the form and continues to run without exiting the application even though the only form loaded is closed.

The main form Closing method does not get called when the X is pressed because the form is hidden when the x is pressed. Form.Deactivated is called but not Form.Closing.

How can i catch the the even when the X is pressed ? (Then I can implement Application.Exit())

Comment: if you have threads, set IsBackground = true; on hem so they close with the main form

Comment: How do you press the "X" close button of the form when it is hidden ??

Comment: Would you please provide the code in program.cs file ...

Comment: Have you written some code to hide the form? Can you post some code, in particular the contents of the 'Main' method

Comment: This is normal behaviour onder WinCE....

Comment: Main Method simply Application.Run(new FormName());
Pressing the X button forces the main form to hide rather than close.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have timer or thread that is running. If so stop those.

Comment: There are no timers or threads - the application is amazingly simple

Answer (score 1):

I guess in *Program.cs*, you call `Application.Run` passing the main form as parameter. If so, the app won't exit until the main form closes.
To catch the event when X button is pressed, add event handler to **secondary** form's `Closed` event, not the main form's. In that event, call main form's `Close` method (or `Application.Exit`).

Comment: I guess in Program.cs, you call Application.Run passing the main form as parameter. If so, the app won't exit until the main form closes.

Comment: "I guess in Program.cs, you call Application.Run passing the main form as parameter. If so, the app won't exit until the main form closes."

This is correct Application.Run(new formname());

"To catch the event when X button is pressed, add event handler to secondary form's Closed event, not the main form's. In that event, call main form's Close method (or Application.Exit)."

I have tried this already. The secondary form is not even instanciated when i try to close the main form.

Comment: Let's call them formA and formB. Which is passed to Application.Run? Which is hidden? On which one you press X?